# Homogeneous matrix to represent rotation out of plane?

Tags: matrices, stereographic-projections

How to represent 2D homoheneous projection matrix

$M=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
m_{00} & m_{01} & m_{02} \\
m_{10} & m_{11} & m_{12} \\
m_{20} & m_{21} & w \end{array} \right)$

for rotation by angle $\alpha$ out of plane?

Suppose distance from plane to eye is known too.

May be there is a formula for all possible rotations?

Comment: Euler angles are one way to define a rotation...

Comment: Is there a formula for Euler angles?

Comment: Google knows all.  Or at least they can point you to someone that does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles